# The type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection' has no constructors defined

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, user-accounts

I need to get users within `SPFieldUserValueCollection` and set them inside `SPUserCollection`, but I have the following build error:

> The type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection' has no constructors defined

```
 SPFieldUserValueCollection employees = item["employees"] as SPFieldUserValueCollection;
            SPUserCollection users = new SPUserCollection();

            if (values != null)
            {
                foreach (SPFieldUserValue userValue in employees)
                {
                    users.Add(userValue.User.LoginName, userValue.User.Email, userValue.User.Name, userValue.User.Notes);
                }

                return users;
            }
```

How I can initialize `SPUserCollection`?

Answer (score 0):

Use instead:

```
List<SPUser> users = new List<SPUser>(); 
//SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(userValue.User.LoginName);
users.add(user);
```

So... your code:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPFieldUserValueCollection employees = item["employees"] as SPFieldUserValueCollection;
List<SPUser> users = new List<SPUser>();

if (values != null)
{
    foreach (SPFieldUserValue userValue in employees)
    {
        SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(userValue.User.LoginName);
        users.Add(user);
    }

    return users;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @domsen, my question for understand how work with SP code, not for solve specific issue. and the question is "How I can initialize SPUserCollection?"

Comment: I think you cant realy initialzie a "new" UserCollection, but im not realy sure... you can initialize an existing one by doing something like spusercollection users = web.AllUsers or something else... I came across this issue, too - a lot of times.... so I decided to do this with this way :)

Comment: thank you, I'll reflect the code and check how they do it